# Unity Parse SDK doesn't seem to be connecting

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am trying to setup Parse API which is running on back4app which is a hosting website for the Parse API. I created a script that connects to the server and then creates a parse object and saves it to the cloud after, but its seems as if its either not connecting or creating the object correctly.

Here is my Code:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    try {
        ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration {
            ApplicationId = appID,
            WindowsKey = dotnetKey,
            Server = serverURL
        });
    }
    catch(Parse.ParseException e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Woops("+e+")");
    }

    StartCoroutine(testObject());
}

// Test Function
IEnumerator testObject()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);

    try {
        ParseObject testObj = new ParseObject("Test");
        testObj["Testvalue"] = "Testy";
        testObj.SaveAsync();
    }
    catch (Parse.ParseException e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Woops(" + e + ")");
    }

    Debug.Log("New Object Created");
}
```

Here is the line for declaring the serverURL:

```
private string serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
```

The other ones are confidential as they are access keys.
I also tried it using with `System.Exception` and no errors were returned and there was nothing in the parse dashboard. All help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I got a fix, I found a source code fork online and then built it within VS and imported it into unity. Here is the link: https://github.com/supersolid/Parse-SDK-dotNET/tree/release/1.7.0 When you open the .sln change it to release and mixed platform, then build it and import it into your unity project.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I have the exact same issue as OP and it won't connect. Did you guys solve this some other way in the end?

Comment: hi @SebastianMaj -- did you have any luck with back4app and Unity? I'm really interested to see what it's like.